# Issue with saving and then retrieving hash table in Rails and memcached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash, memcached, hashtable

I am using Ruby on Rails and memcached on my windows machine. I create a hash and then store it in memcached using Rails. Before I save it, the class type of that variable is hash. When I read from cache, the variable class ends up being array... Any help on avoiding this? Can't I store the hash in the memcached using Rails? Why is the type changing on retrieval? Thanks.

Sample code...

```
my_hash = Hash.new
my_hash["foo"] = 23
my_hash["bar"] = 33
#my_hash.class.to_s => hash
Rails.cache.write("key1", my_hash)

retrieved_hash = Rails.cache.read("key1")
#retrieved_hash.class.to_s => array
```

Comment: Can you post up the result of doing .inspect on the object you get back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no change in type of class

```
1.9.3p194 :014 > my_hash = Hash.new
 => {} 
1.9.3p194 :015 > my_hash["foo"] = 23
 => 23 
1.9.3p194 :016 > my_hash["bar"] = 33
 => 33 
1.9.3p194 :017 > my_hash.class
 => Hash 
1.9.3p194 :018 > Rails.cache.write("key1", my_hash)
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :019 > retrieved_hash = Rails.cache.read("key1")
 => {"foo"=>23, "bar"=>33} 
1.9.3p194 :020 > retrieved_hash.class
 => Hash
```

In both case class is same as Hash.

Comment: You are right. In my code, in another place, I was using the same hash key and there I was writing the array which was overriding what I wrote previously. Thanks for confirming that this should have worked.